# Matplotlib subplot: imshow + plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I want to create a plot that looks like the image below. There are two unique plots in the figure. `img1` was generated using `plt.imshow()`, while `img2` was generated using `plt.plot()`. The code I used to generate each of the plots is provided below

```
plt.clf()
plt.imshow(my_matrix)
plt.savefig("mymatrix.png")

plt.clf()
plt.plot(x,y,'o-')
plt.savefig("myplot.png")
```

The matrix used in `img1` is `64x64`. The same range for `img2`'s x-axis (`x=range(64)`). Ideally, the x-axes of the two `img2`'s align with the axes of `img1`.

It is important to note that the final image is reminiscent of seaborn's `jointplot()`, but the marginal subplots (`img2`) in the image below do not show distribution plots.

[image: Ideal output with annotation]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `make_axes_locatable` functionality of the `mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1` to create shared axes along both directions of the central `imshow` plot.

Here is an example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import make_axes_locatable
import numpy as np; np.random.seed(0)

Z = np.random.poisson(lam=6, size=(64,64))
x = np.mean(Z, axis=0)
y = np.mean(Z, axis=1)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.imshow(Z)

# create new axes on the right and on the top of the current axes.
divider = make_axes_locatable(ax)
axtop = divider.append_axes("top", size=1.2, pad=0.3, sharex=ax)
axright = divider.append_axes("right", size=1.2, pad=0.4, sharey=ax)
#plot to the new axes
axtop.plot(np.arange(len(x)), x, marker="o", ms=1, mfc="k", mec="k")
axright.plot(y, np.arange(len(y)), marker="o", ms=1, mfc="k", mec="k")
#adjust margins
axright.margins(y=0)
axtop.margins(x=0)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome! This is what I need! Thanks!