# Matplotlib: Subplot heights with squared imshow

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to plot a three-panel figure, with an `imshow` on the top and two other plots below. My `imshow` is has the same x and y dimensions, ie. is squared. The two other plots have the same x dimension, they can therefore share the x axis. However, how do I specify that all three panels have the same width?

This is my code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(0,100,20)
y = np.sin(x)
z = np.random.rand(100,100)

fig, (ax, ax2, ax3) = plt.subplots(nrows=3, sharex=True, figsize=(10,10), gridspec_kw={"height_ratios": [2,1,1]})

# "main" plot
ax.imshow(z)

# accessory plot #1
ax2.plot(x, y)
ax2.set_xlim(0,99)

# accessory plot #2
ax3.plot(x*2, y)

plt.show()
```

I don't understand the behavior here, why does my `imshow` not have the correct width like the two panels below?
I found a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43352931/matplotlib-subplot-imshow-plot), but as far as I understand this can only create one additional axis per side?

This is my current output:
[image: How it looks]

And I would like it to look like this:

[image: How it should look like]

Comment: Can you include the output of your current code, and perhaps a small figure/drawing showing what you need instead? This could be just me, but I find it a little hard to parse your written explanation.

Comment: I did! thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Layout is defnitely something matplotlib could use some work on. What is happening is that you have a square figure, with `height_ratios=[2, 1, 1]`: the first axis (where you plot the image) has double the height of the other two. But the image you are plotting is also square, so it is using all the available height, while it has "white" space on the horizontal direction.

Try to play with `figsize` and maybe the `height_ratios`, something like this:

```
fig, (ax, ax2, ax3) = plt.subplots(nrows=3, sharex=True, figsize=(6,12), gridspec_kw={"height_ratios": [4,1,1]})
```

[image]